# How to consume messages from Websocket client which sends out messages continously

Tags: java, spring-websocket

I have been given a jar which can be executed with the below command for getting the real time messages,

```
java -jar realtimemessage.jar wss://realtimemessage.website.com/subscribe/
```

This command prints the messages in console

I could call the same in java code using below code since the realtimemessage.jar has the WebSocketClient class file,

```
String[] args= { "wss://realtimemessage.website.com/subscribe/"};
WebSocketClient.main(args);
```

Since it is a continuous stream of messages being printed in console, how can I get each message and process them using my Java code?

Comment: You have to consult with developers of that `realtimemessage.jar`. I'm pretty sure there should be somehow to stream those messages to the callback provided. That's just nature of the `WebSocketClient.main()` to print them into the console.

Comment: @ArtemBilan, so I have to ask for a callback function to the developers of `realtimemessage.jar`?

Comment: I think so. You may just decompile that `WebSocketClient` and see what really you can do yourself to hook to that stream.